# How to track the value of target function during ortools mixed-integer-programming solving process?

Tags: python, or-tools, scip

I'm using ortools SCIP to solve a really large mixed-integer-programming problem.

```
solver = pywraplp.Solver_CreateSolver('SCIP')

"""
Problem Definition Is Omitted Here
"""

solver.Minimize(target_function)

status = solver.Solve()
```

That problem costs more than 30 minutes.

The SCIP uses branch-cut-and-price to solve the mixed-integer-programming problem.

Each time, the SCIP would cut some branches.

So, my question is, how to print the value of the target function, after each cut(after each iteration)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a SCIP question and not an OR-Tools one.

So how would you do it with the SCIP binary or library.

If you know how to do this, I believe there are no mechanism in OR-Tools linear solver wrappers to support that, but maybe there is a parameter to display that kind of info. In that case, you should be able to set it directly through the API.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm using python ortools library to use SCIP

Comment: Yes but it only offers a subset of what Scip library do. Is what you ask even feasible with the Scip api?